# If you fold a rectangular piece of paper in half

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics, word-problem

If you fold a rectangular piece of paper in half and the resulting
    rectangles have the same aspect ratio as the original rectangle,
    then what is the aspect ratio of the rectangles?

Comment: What's the solution needing verification?

Comment: Agreed. This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\text{width}}{\text{lengh}}=\sqrt{2}
$$

[Have a look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size)

Answer (score 0):

Assume the original rectangle is $x$ wide and $a \cdot x$ long, where a is the requested aspect ratio. If we fold the paper in half (lengthwise), the resulting rectangles will be $\frac{a \cdot x}{2}$ wide and $x$ long. Equating these ratios, we find that

> $$a = \frac{1}{a / 2} = \frac{2}{a}$$

Solving this simple equation yields

> $$a=\sqrt{2}$$